# How to call abstract method from interface

Tags: craft3, php, user-interface

I would like to use a method of `fileExists`. It belongs to `VolumeInterface`.
https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-volumeinterface.html

I suppose the code would be like `\craft\base\Volume::fileExists($path)`.

However, Craft returns an error;

```
Non-static method craft\base\VolumeInterface::fileExists() cannot be called statically
```

Could I ask how I should modify the code?

Answer (score 1):

The normal way would be to instantiate and call non-statically like this:

`(new \craft\base\Volume)->fileExists($path);`

...However, that won't work here because it's an abstract class, which, by definition, cannot be instantiated. Assuming you're dealing with an `Asset` element(?), try calling `getVolume()` and then you should be able to call `fileExists()` from there. E.g:

`$asset->getVolume()->fileExists();`

Comment: Yes, I would like to get asset's existence. However, it is from its URL, not $asset. For example, I want to get if the file exist; "assets/doc/RegionA/statement.pdf"

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative way to find out if the asset exists or not, with filename, asset query and folder id.
It is like;

```
{% set asset_query = craft.assets().filename(filename).folderId(folderID).all() %}
```

And if the query's length is 1 or more, it means the asset file exists.